# Event vs MouseEvent

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events, mouseevent, onclicklistener

I'm writing a chrome extension and I want to do something when shiftKey is pressed while clicking on an item. I know how to get the shiftkey:

```
event.shiftKey
```

But the problem is sometimes the `event` object passed to the `click` handler is of type `Event` and sometimes it's of type `MouseEvent` and there is no property of `shiftKey` when the event is of type `Event`..
This is when I add the eventListener:

```
elemet.addEventListener('click', handleOnClick);
```

Here is the handleOnClick function:

```
function handleOnClick(event) {
    console.log(event);
    if (event.shiftKey) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Here is what I see in chrome console:
Sometimes:

```
Event {isTrusted: false, type: "click", ...}
```

And the if statement is not executed in this case even when the shift key is pressed.

Sometimes:

```
MouseEvent {isTrusted: true, screenX: -1611, screenY: -91, clientX: 766, clientY: 90, …}
```

if statement is executed in this case when the shift key is pressed.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Provide a [mcve]

Comment: You might also want to check out [`event.getModifierState('Shift')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/getModifierState)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this in case someone else runs into the same problem.
I fixed this by doing `element.onmousedown = handleOnClick;` instead of `element.addEventListener('click', handleOnClick);`.
Now the `event` passed to `handleOnClick` is always `MouseEvent` and I can do `event.shiftKey`.

Comment: This can't be the solution. A `click` event will always pass a `MouseEvent`. I think you are just seeing a symptom of a larger issue.

Answer (score 0):

> I know how to get the shiftkey: `event.shiftKey`

Well, not exactly. The event has to be one that supports it. The standard `Event` that all others inherit from, doesn't have a `.shiftKey` property. Keyboard events, like `keyup` and `keydown` (not `keypress`) will.

Now, if you are correctly setting up a `click` event handler, then the **[`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent)** is what will fire when a `click` occurs and a `MouseEvent` also has a **[`.shiftKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/shiftKey)** property.

So, as long as you are handling a `click` (which is a `MouseEvent`), you will always be able to get the `event.shiftKey`:

```js
$(document).on('click', function(e){
  console.log(e.shiftKey);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Apparently, `Event` does not have a shiftKey property.. It returns undefined when I do `console.log(event.shiftKey);`

Comment: I understand what you mean and I know I should get `MouseEvent` when clicked on an item. And when I get `MouseEvent`, everything is fine and I can get the shiftKey prop. But SOMETIMES (on some screens) I get `Event` when clicked on an element (instead of `MouseEvent`). My code doesn't change! I'm just testing on different tabs of a website.

Comment: @parisa You'll need to show the HTML and the code that you are using to set up your `click` event handler.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I figured it out.

Comment: @parisa Please post an edit to your question with what your solution was and please up vote any/all answers that were helpful along with marking any answer that you may feel solved your issue as "the" answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use another event handler that listens for keypress events and set a variable that is accessible by both listeners and keeps the state of the shift key. Example:

```js
var shiftPressed = false;

test.onclick = (evt)=>console.log(shiftPressed ? 'With shift' : 'No shift');

window.onkeydown = (evt)=>{shiftPressed = evt.shiftKey;};
window.onkeyup = (evt)=>{shiftPressed = evt.shiftKey;};
```

```html
<button id='test'>Click Me with and without shift!</button>
```

Remember you have to click in the document in order for it to have focus before testing.

Comment: This is a workaround that is not necessary. You can get the status of the `SHIFT` key during a MouseEvent.